# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors, for a given differential operator mapping into the 3-d space of quasi-polynomials.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Given the differential operator $D = \frac{d^2}{dt^2}+k^2I$ is a linear mapping on the 3-dimensional space of quasi-polynomials: 
>   $e^{-t}(a_2t^2 + a_1t+a_0)$
>   a) Using $a_0, a_1, a_2$ as coordinates, write out the corresponding matrix.
>   b) Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of D.

This is a question in which I actually have the solution because the tutorial has solutions, but I don't really understand some of the solution and I need to ask these questions.
for a) the solution goes as follows:

> a) We have a basis $e^{-t}, te^{-t}, t^2e^{-t}$. Now
>   $D(e^{-t}) = e^{-t}+k^2e^{-t}=(1+k^2)e^{-t} \\
> D(te^{-t}) = te^{-t}-2e^{-t}+k^2te^{-t}=(1+k^2)te^{-t}-2e^{-t} \\
> D(t^2e^{-t}) = t^2e^{-t} - 4te^{-t}+2e^{-t}+k^2e^{-t}=(1+k^2)t^2e^{-t}-4te^{-t}+2e^{-t}$
>   which gives the matrix
>
> $\begin{bmatrix}
> 1+k^2 & -2 & 2 \\
> 0 & 1+k^2 & -4 \\
> 0 & 0 & 1+k^2
> \end{bmatrix}$

So my question about part a) solution is. How does one know the basis is $e^{-t}, te^{-t}, t^2e^{-t}$? Is this because these are the three vectors that we are making linear combinations of with $a_0, a_1$ and $a_2$?

The solution for part b) is simply this:

> b) The only eigenvalue is $1 + k^2$ with algebraic multiplicity 3 and there is only one eigenvector $e^{-t}$

My question for part b) is, how did they determine the eigenvector? I thought you would take the kernel of the above matrix, but I cannot see how we can get a solution that would equate to $0$.

Comment: The top row of the matrix consists of all the coefficients in front of $e^{-t}$. The second row consists of all the coefficients in front ot of $te^{-t}$ and the third row consists of all coefficients in front of $t^2e^{-t}$. What is the reasoning behind how this matrix was built?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to part a): each quasi-polynomials in the space above has the form $a_0e^{-t}+a_1te^{-t}+a_2t^2e^{-t}$, hence is a linear combination of $e^{-t}, te^{-t}, t^2e^{-t}$.

Answer to part b): solve the linear system

$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -2 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & -4 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} * \begin{bmatrix}
a_0 \\
a_1 \\
a_2
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}$

.

Comment: Ok, thanks for part a). For part b) I can see that $a_2$ and $a_1$ will equal $0$. $a_0$ can be anything.I really still don't understand. Why were the eigenvalues removed to solve the system? Also $a_0$ is the coefficent in front of $e^{-t}$ not $e^{-t}$ itself? I think part of my misunderstanding is I'm not 100% on how they built that matrix in the first place.

Comment: If $ \lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then any solution $x \ne 0$ of $(A- \lambda E)x=0$ is an eigenvector.

Comment: Ahh, I think I see now. This relates to the rule that for triangular matrices the eigenvalues are the diagonal entries. So $D-\lambda I$ results in the matrix you stated above that I had to solve.

Comment: Ok that's good thanks @Fred, but I still not sure how they related it back to $e^{-t}$

Comment: Thanks for your help @Fred.